# Devise authenticate redirect best practices with routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have two models, User and Vendor.

I have `!authenticate_{model}` in their respected controllers.

Although, my routes looks like this:

```
  authenticated :user do
    get 'company/dashboard' => 'company_dashboard#dashboard'
    ...
    root :to => 'company_dashboard#dashboard'   
  end

  authenticated :vendor do
    get 'vendor/dashboard' => 'vendor_dashboard#dashboard'
    ...
    root :to => 'vendor_dashboard#dashboard'   
  end

  root :to => 'home#index'
```

Now, when a session expires and the page is reloaded, it gives routing error `no route mathes GET company/dashboard` and no redirect is performed.

Is setting up the routes this way a mistake?

When i remove the `authenticated :{modelname} do` it works as expected with the redirects.

When is using the the `authenticated :{modelname} do` a best case scenerio? For rooting a page after sign-in? anything else?

And should i keep it the way i have it with the `authenticated :{modelname} do`? Is there a way to initiate the redirect as wanted?

Comment: I would define the `get 'company/dashboard' => 'company_dashboard#dashboard'` and `get 'vendor/dashboard' => 'vendor_dashboard#dashboard'` routes outside the `authenticated` block. Using `authenticated do ... end` makes sense to create a dynamic root path but not for actual routes with a path. Authorization is not a job for the routing layer as unauthorized access is treated as a 404 instead of redirecting to the sign in.

Comment: Okay thanks, that makes sense.  Wanted to confirm that before applying it.  appreciate it !